# How to re-order children using ContentChildren and QueryList

Tags: angular

I've a tabs component with a collection of tab component. The collection of tabs are stored as a `QueryList` using the `ContentChildren`. How can I re-oder the children using `QueryList`?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tab',
  template: `
    <p>{{title}}</p>
  `,
})
export class TabComponent {
  @Input() title;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'tabs',
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
})
export class TabsComponent {
 @ContentChildren(TabComponent) tabs: QueryList<TabComponent>

 ngAfterContentInit() {
   this.tabs.forEach(tabInstance => console.log(tabInstance))
 }

 swap() {
   console.log('swapping...');
   const swapped = this.tabs.toArray().reverse();
   this.tabs.reset(swapped);
 }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <tabs>
     <tab title="One"></tab>
     <tab title="Two"></tab>
    </tabs>
    <button (click)="swap()">Swap</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild(TabsComponent) tabs;

  swap() {
    this.tabs.swap();
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same question. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets Not yet. I'll share here once I find it.

Answer (score 4):

You could extract an array from `QueryList`, swap items and then reset the query list:

```js
// ...
const arr = this.tabs.toArray();

// ...
// swap elements as desired
// ...

this.tabs.reset(arr);
```